# Make a cross-platform standalone Python desktop app when the GUI uses PyQt4, not installed on computer

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4, py2app

I made a GUI Python program using the PyQt4 framework on a Linux computer, and now I am on a MacBook Pro and I would like to be able to package my program. The program imports PyQt4 (obviously), along with other libraries like Pandas. I just tried downloading PyQt4 on my OS but do not know exactly what is going on. I just want to be able to include the necessary PyQt4 files in the package so that any user can run my program without having to download PyQt4. Is that possible?

Also, I'm using py2app to try to package this desktop app. Others have suggested using MacPorts along with py2app, and I tried downloading MacPorts but was also unable to figure that out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!